# Пример передачи любой формы ajax с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста пример для передачи любой формы ajax с помощью javascript

Comment: Неужели в интернете ни одного примера не нашлось?

Comment: Неужели в интернете ни одного примера не нашлось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form method="post"><input type="text" name="someinput" value=""></form>


var formElement = document.querySelector("form");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "submitform.php");
request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

Как спросили, так и ответили :) (первый же запрос в google выдает максимальную инфу) https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Добавьте объяснение к вашему ответу или он будет отмечен, как ответ низкого качества :)